# Foundation top-bar doesn't collapse or stay sticky on mobile breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a site under development here: http://www.mudquarters.com

If you view it on mobile or re-size your window to the break point you will get the menu toggle icon. After you click it it scrolls to the appropriate anchor, however it loses its "fixed" class and it also remains open at the top of the page. Oddly, the anchor is compensating for the 75px height of the top-bar even though it remains at the top of the page. I get the same bug when using "sticky".

I would like the top-bar to stay fixed and collapse while scrolling to the anchor.

This is my code:

HTML

```
<div class="fixed">
    <nav class="top-bar">
        <ul class="title-area">
            <li class="small-8 large-12 logo-container"><a href="#"><img src="img/MudQuarters_Logo.png"></a></li>
            <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
        </ul>

    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="#brand">BRAND</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lifestyle">LIFESTYLE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#online">ONLINE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#stores">IN STORES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#trenches">IN THE TRENCHES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team">TEAM</a></li>
            <li><a href="#opportunity">OPPORTUNITY</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS Override

```
.top-bar {
overflow: hidden;
height: 75px;
line-height: 75px;
position: relative;
background: #000000;
padding: 0 20px; }

.top-bar.expanded {
background-color: #000000; }
.top-bar.expanded .title-area {
background: #000000; }
.top-bar.expanded .toggle-topbar a {
color: #FFFFFF; }
.top-bar.expanded .toggle-topbar a span {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 16px 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 22px 0 1px #FFFFFF;
box-shadow: 0 10px 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 16px 0 1px #FFFFFF, 0 22px 0 1px #FFFFFF; }

.logo-container {
line-height: 75px; }

.top-bar-section li a:not(.button) {
line-height: 75px;
padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
background: #000000; }
```

I have not made any changes to Foundation's default JS file.

Comment: For some reason it is removing the fixed class when you click on the menu button.  It then gets placed back in the class when the menu button is clicked again (when it closes).  I know you said that the js file was not touched, but maybe you have some other js that is causing this?

Comment: I don't think the JS was written for a single-page with the smooth scroll JS. It needs to collapse, remain fixed and then smooth scroll to anchor. Perhaps its an ordering thing?

Comment: It could be.  I would open an issue on github and see what they say.